# Parentheses after Typing Environment

Tags: type-theory, notation

I've been reading about System F Omega lately, and I keep stumbling across a construct in typing rules that I cannot find an explanation of: `Γ(x) = k`. For example, in [A Short Introduction to Systems F and F Omega](http://babel.ls.fi.upm.es/~pablo/Papers/Notes/f-fw.pdf):

```
Γ(a) = k
--------
Γ ⊢ a : k
```

I see the same construct in [Hereditary Substitution for Stratified System F](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~astump/papers/pstt-2010.pdf). I understand the bottom part fine. It would read something like: "In context `Γ`, `a` has kind `k`". I've not been able to find an explanation of the top part, and the sources I referenced both assume familiarity with this construct. If I had to guess, I suspect that it means something like "In context `a`, running a kind-checking algorithm on `a` gives you kind `k` as the result". Is that accurate? What online resources describe this construct?

Comment: Contexts are association lists: Each variable is associated a type; this is like a key-value map or a dictionary in programming ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Gamma$ here is overloaded notation. The meaning of the expression $\Gamma(x) = \tau$ above the inference line here is given under the "**Type rules.**" section of [A Short Introduction to Systems F and F Omega](http://babel.ls.fi.upm.es/~pablo/Papers/Notes/f-fw.pdf) on page 5. In this setting, $\Gamma$ is an inductively-defined function sending variables (in $\Gamma$ considered as a context, i.e. a list of variables) to their types.

A more illustrative, syntactic way to write the rule you give might be: $\frac{}{\Gamma,\ x : \tau\ \vdash x : \tau}$, where $\Gamma$ ranges freely over contexts. Note that the order of variables in a context here does not matter, so this rule allows us to project any variable in a context as a term.

Answer (score 1):

To add to varkor's answer:

A context is just a function sending (some) variables to their types.

So the rule is saying: "If $\Gamma$ assigns the type $\tau$ to variable $x$, then we can deduce $\Gamma \vdash x : \tau$."